# эхо бот не реагирует(aiogram)

Tags: python, бот, telegram

вот код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

import os

bot=Bot(token=os.getenv('TOKEN'))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message : types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)
    await message.reply(message.text)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.text)

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

активирую через бат файл, никаких ошибок
но в самом телеграме бот не реагирует.

Answer (score 0):

я оказывается не тот токен использавал, всё заработало

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).